# How can I allow all users to run a given command via sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo

I know how to create a command which a given user can execute via `sudo`. I have a given command I want to allow *any user* to be able to execute via `sudo` without entering a password. What would I put in my /etc/sudoers file in order to make that happen?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question.  I looked in `man sudoers` once and did not find the answer.  I looked into `man sudoers` a second time, more carefully.  Still I failed, TMI!  Then, thanks to the answers here I grepped `man sudoers` and found why this is working.  Looks like you first need to know how to do it before you can understand `man sudoers`.  Sigh!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A section like this in your sudoers is probably what you want.

```
Cmnd_Alias NAMEOFTHIS=/usr/bin/program
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: NAMEOFTHIS
```

Comment: Doesn't that grant access just to user *username*? Is there a wildcard I can use instead? I want any authenticated user to be able to execute the command.

Comment: Then use a group they are all members of.

Comment: Thanks! I swear I tried that but I forgot a space, so it wasn't working!

Comment: @Broam: they're not all members of a single group, and I wanted an easier solution.

Comment: If it's not *all* users, I'd add a group simply because this is membership of something you wish to track - who can `sudo` this way.

Comment: If you really don't want to add a group (beats me why not) and still need individual users, use `User_Alias SOMEUSERS = user1, user2`.

Answer (score 21):

You might consider the [SUID bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).  Certain programs require root privileges and use the SUID bit, such as `passwd`.

If sudo is the better choice for you, you could use:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/command
```

Comment: It's a shell script which restarts a local caching nameserver... so SUID won't work in this case, right?

Comment: Zoredache beat me in the time it took for me to test my recommended solution.  =)

Comment: While he was simultaneously harassing me in chat for posting such an easy question, no less!

Comment: @Josh:then don't post easy questions :-)

Comment: @Bart: HAHA -- I wasn't saying I didn't deserve it, I was just commenting that Zoredache was able to not only answer faster than Werner, but answer faster *while simultaneously harassing me* :-)

Comment: @Josh: Sounds like a neat feature, actually. Multiharassitasking.