# Show quota limit of user's home directory

Tags: linux, btrfs

What I am trying to do is to get quota limit of current system user's home directory, which is btrfs quota-enabled, using the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/btrfs qgroup show-reF ~/
```

The above command outputs the following error:

```
ERROR: can't list qgroups: Operation not permitted
```

Above command works well for root user. But I wanted to allow users to check the disk usage of their home directory as their is quota limit on users home directory.

I added the user to group of /usr/sbin/btrfs command, but it did not help. can anybody explain the cause of the error? and probably how to resolve it?

Comment: If you want to set quotas per user, wouldn't it make more sense to use the regular quota system instead of btrfs quotas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the currently given information and because of the nature of [BTRFS Quota groups](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Qgroups.html)

> *... Above command works well for root user ... Can anybody explain the cause of the error?*

the command needs to run under higher rights, as `root`. See in example the thread under [How to display quota limit on BTRFS subvolume?](https://serverfault.com/questions/797219/).

> *But I wanted to allow users to check ...*

In order to do so you could [allow all users to run a given command via `sudo`](https://serverfault.com/questions/184072/) and would need to add to the `/etc/sudoers` file in example

```bash
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/btrfs qgroup show-reF ~/
```

which can then just be executed by the user via

```bash
sudo /usr/sbin/btrfs qgroup show-reF ~/
```

You may also think about to [introduce an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378477/) for the command with [`Cmnd_Alias`](https://serverfault.com/a/184074/448950) and see [How do I use command arguments with `Cmnd_Alias` in `sudoers`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178069/)

Comment: You are definitely right. That worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you may also have a look into [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accept if it answer your question.